# plot circles where size depends number of votes (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geometry

The data are from 25 voters who each give a score (1 to 5) on 2 cases. I am particularly interested in one of the voters, and would like to visualize the results by circles in various sizes. The idea is:

```
Y-axis: the scores (1 to 5).  
X-axis: the cases (1 to 2).
```

Now for each X we visualize the distribution of the 25 scores by 5 circles of varying size. Since we are extra interested in one voter, say voter number 7, we make the circles that correspond to his/her votes red and the other circles blue.

I can arrange the data in any way needed but would like some direction of which python package and function to use.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

voter = np.tile(np.arange(25), 2)
votes = random.choices(np.arange(5), k=50)
votes = np.array(votes) + 1
case = np.repeat([1, 2], 25)

data = pd.DataFrame({'voter': voter, 'case': case, 'votes': votes})
data
```

[Hand made idea of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZijn.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what exactly are you asking for. Your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want to know how to draw a circle or how to color it or what? You can create the circle manually or use the existing functions by providing the circle's origin and R or using the rectangle that surrounds it. Does your circles size describes the number of votes or you just want a circle at a certain position in the graph instead of a simple point.

Comment: The circle size should somehow convey an idea of how many voted, say, 3. Would like help mainly with drawing the circles. Coloring I can probably figure out one I have a template. Thanks. By the way, in the figure provided I accidently made one circle too many red.

Comment: Seems you're looking for a [`scatter` plot](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html). Can you go more in detail what the actual problem would be using such scatter?

Comment: You can create circles using the Circle() class from the matplotlib.patches module.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, that solves the problem. Sorry for not realizing this immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest answer if someone need a similar plot.

```
color = data[(data.voter == 4)].votes

df = data.groupby(['case', 'votes'], as_index=False).agg('count')
df['c'] = np.repeat('g', len(df))

for i, j in enumerate(color):
    a = (df.case == i + 1) & (df.votes == j)
    df['c'].where(~a, 'b', inplace=True)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.scatter(x = df.case,
            y= df.votes,
            s=df.voter * 100,
            alpha=0.5,
            color=df.c)
plt.ylabel("ISUP score")
plt.xlabel("Cases")
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
plt.show()
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNeXO.png)